# How do i convert this equation into the node editor?

Tags: node-editor, mathematics

How do I make this in the node editor?
I don't get how to go around y=(-x)

[image]

Comment: Hello :). If you don't mind me asking, what are such equations in the node editor used for? I have honestly no idea.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ ...for example .. [procedural texturing](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llByzz)

Comment: @RobinBetts Oh, thank you :).

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Labelled  'Layout > Reroute' nodelets not necessary, but often helpful.

Alternatively, if you have complex expressions to convert, you might consider using @Rich Sedman's [Node-Expressions add-on](https://blender-addons.org/node-expressions-addon/), which could generate a group like this:

[image]

It's best to be quite explicit with your bracketing.. In this example, when I didn't bracket the unary minus on `x`, the negative was applied to the whole expression, rather than binding to the variable. This is expected Python.. but maybe not obvious.